# RUBY: Read text file into 2D array, while also removing newlines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops

I'm trying to input text from a file, ignoring the first line, and adding each character to a 2D array at a separate index [[],[]].  So far I can add the characters to their own index but can't remove the newline characters with .chomp or etc.

I want my end result to be

```
[['*','.','.','.']","['.','.','*','.']","['.','.','.','.']]
```

So that `[0][0]` will return `*` for example, and `[0]` will return `*...`

Right now I'm returning

```
[['*','.','.','.',"\n"]","['.','.','*','.',"\n"]","['.','.','.','.',"\n"]]
```

The code in question is:

```
def load_board(file)
    board = File.readlines(file)[1..-1].map do |line|
        line.split("").map(&:to_s)
    end
end

origin_board = load_board('mines.txt')
print origin_board
```

If I try the following code:

```
def load_board(file)
    board = File.readlines(file)[1..-1].map do |line|
        line.split.map(&:to_s)
    end
end

origin_board = load_board('mines.txt')
print origin_board
```

I end up with a 2D array like:

```
[["*..."],["..*."],["...."]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Stripping your input should help:

```
def load_board(file)
    board = File.readlines(file)[1..-1].map do |line|
        #    ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
        line.strip.split("").map(&:to_s)
    end
end
```

[`String#strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) will remove leading-trailing blanks from a string. The other option is not to use `readlines` in favour of `read` and `split` by `$/` (line separator):

```
def load_board(file)
    board = File.read(file).split($/)[1..-1].map do |line|
        line.split("").map(&:to_s)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a .chomp before the .split, like this:

```
def load_board(file)
    board = File.readlines(file)[1..-1].map do |line|
        line.chomp.split("").map(&:to_s)
    end
end
```

Haven't exactly tested it but did some fiddling and it should work http://repl.it/hgJ/1.